# ClassCircularityError when running Tomcat 6 from Eclipse

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm using Eclipse 3.5, with my Tomcat runtime set as Tomcat 6.0.26.  My Java VM is JDK 1.6.17 (Mac OS X).

When I try to run a web application from an Eclipse Java EE perspective I keep seeing this error in the console:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCircularityError: java/util/logging/LogRecord
 at com.adsafe.util.SimpleFormatter.format(SimpleFormatter.java:11)
 at java.util.logging.StreamHandler.publish(StreamHandler.java:179)
 at java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.publish(ConsoleHandler.java:88)
 at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:458)
 at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:480)
 at java.util.logging.Logger.logp(Logger.java:596)
 at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.log(DirectJDKLog.java:165)
 at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.info(DirectJDKLog.java:115)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log(ApplicationContext.java:644)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.log(ApplicationContextFacade.java:251)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.unavailable(StandardWrapper.java:1327)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1130)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:993)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4187)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4496)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
 ... 6 more
```

java/util/logging/**LogRecord** implements **Serializable**, so I am not sure where the circular reference could have creeped in.

Has anyone seen this before and know how to fix this?

Comment: This Adsafe? http://www.adsafe.org/

Comment: This might be the official bug: http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-740 The Logback creator seems to think it's a Tomcat issue.

Answer (score 7):

I was able to circumvent this problem by moving the `<contextListener ...>` to the very end of the configuration file (previously, I had it at the beginning of the file). The error remains really weird, though.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is solved if you insert this snippet into your logback configuration:

```
<!-- LEVEL CAN NOT BE DEBUG -->
<logger name="org.apache" level="INFO"></logger>
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked nicely. You can even do that only for `org.apache.catalina`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why this resolved the problem, but setting the default level to INFO made this go away for me

.level = INFO

Comment: That's because the Circularity Error occurs when the Webapp class loader loads the logger classes. Doing that, it outputs a debug message to the log. For this it will need to load the logger classes. Doing that ... you see where this is getting. Setting the log level to INFO supresses the debug log entry -> loop avoided.

Answer (score 2):

In had the same error when using Logback.

In my case, the problem was I used JUL LevelChangePropagator in my Logback configuration file.

So I just had to remove the following listener

```
<contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator">
    <resetJUL>true</resetJUL>
</contextListener>
```

Comment: removing `LevelChangePropagator` may cause a performance issue: http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#jul-to-slf4j

Comment: @BradCupit I also had this error (and didn't want to stop using the LevelChangePropagator for performance reasons). Though I found it hard to believe, Meriton's solution (below) worked for me and allowed me to keep it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a bit of context: I personally see this message when adding a listener in my `web.xml` to install the [SLF4JBridgeHandler](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/bridge/SLF4JBridgeHandler.html) to bridge `java.util.logging` (JUL) calls to SLF4J. I started to see this as soon as I increased the JUL root logger level from the default (`INFO`) to `FINE`, in order to forward all (well, almost all) messages to SLF4J.

user2543253 comment above was indeed useful, it's a problem that happens at classloading time. I personally solved it by adding a fake direct JUL log call (using a `LogRecord`) before installing the SLF4JBridgeHandler, in order to trigger classloading of JUL classes early. So my listener now does:

```java
java.util.logging.Logger rootLogger = LogManager.getLogManager().getLogger("");
rootLogger.log(new LogRecord(Level.ALL, "bridging of java.uil.logging to SLF4J requested"));
SLF4JBridgeHandler.removeHandlersForRootLogger();
rootLogger.setLevel(Level.FINE);
SLF4JBridgeHandler.install();
```

By the way: it's not strictly a Logback problem, I experience this while not using Logback at all (I'm using the Log4j 1.2 binding).