# Application will not run on Tomcat Server within Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, java-8, maven-3, slf4j, tomcat8

I am running a spring boot application that has suddenly stopped working
I had to upgrade to a different lapptop and when I installed the software - all of a sudden my server will not start

The error I get is as follows when I try to run my code on a tomcat server within eclipse

```
java.lang.ClassCircularityError: java/util/logging/LogRecord
at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.getSLF4JLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:198)
at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.publish(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:287)
at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:738)
at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:765)
at java.util.logging.Logger.logp(Logger.java:930)
at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.log(DirectJDKLog.java:180)
at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.debug(DirectJDKLog.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:369)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:625)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
```

I am using Eclipse Mars (4.5), Java jdk1.8.0_51 and Tomcat 8 apache-tomcat-8.0.24 (same error with apache-tomcat-8.0.23)

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I could try to resolve this?

This problem does not occur if I run my maven target to generate the war file and deploy directly to tomcat - it only happens when I try to run my server from within eclipse

Just to point out - this all works perfectly when i use java 7 version 79 but would like to get it working with Java 8

Comment: Have you checked and tried solution mentioned for this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656565/classcircularityerror-when-running-tomcat-6-from-eclipse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Spring Boot,

Add/Replace the following in the application.properties file -

**logging.level.=INFO** 

or 

**logging.level.root=INFO**