# java.lang.ClassCircularityError: java/util/logging/LogRecord from Tomcat8

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, spring-boot, tomcat8

I have configured logback.xml for my spring boot application. My spring boot version - 1.3.3.RELEASE, java version - 1.8 update 45, tomcat version - 8.

I have put logback.xml file in my local tomcats /lib folder.

Whenever I am running my tomcat without debug configuration it works fine.

But whenever I am trying run server with debug configured in catalina.bat file (with this option - set "JAVA_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket...... ) it displays java.lang.ClassCircularityError: java/util/logging/LogRecord and tomcat window closes.

Detailsed error trace :

```
java.lang.ClassCircularityError: java/util/logging/LogRecord
at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.getSLF4JLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:200)
at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.publish(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:289)
at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:458)
at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:480)
at java.util.logging.Logger.logp(Logger.java:596)
```

I have tried all the solutions given in thread - [ClassCircularityError when running Tomcat 6 from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656565/classcircularityerror-when-running-tomcat-6-from-eclipse)

But nothing is working.

Does anyone faced this issue recently? Is there any solution or workaround for this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you still having this problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**
There are two workarounds:

1. In your project, move the `<contextListener ...>` line in your `logback.xml` configuration file to the end of the file.
2. Instead of `step 1` above, another workaround exists for those who are running `Tomcat` from `Eclipse`. Don't. Instead, run `Tomcat` from the `terminal`:

   > ./catalina.sh start